# Why XMLEventReader / XMLEventWriter unexpectedly changes tab to whitespace in output?

Tags: xml, unicode, character-encoding, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I use XMLEventReader to read xml content with tab inside, later I use XMLEventWriter to write them back to another file. However, 3 tab in the original input have been change to 3 whitespaces in my output. 
Why that happens ? Is that possible it keeps them in the new file?

Please see this piece of code to show 3 tab are changed to 3 white spaces:

```
    public static void testXMLStreamWriter() {
        try {
            final XMLEventFactory xmlEventFactory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
            XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLOutputFactory xmlOutputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLEventWriter xmlEventWriter = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLEventWriter(System.out);

            // here the input contians 3 tabs
            String xmlStr = "<tag>\n" + "<formatter pattern=\"abc           xyz\"/>\n" + "</tag>";

            XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlStr)));

            // adds the event to the consumer.
            xmlEventWriter.add(xmlEventReader);
            xmlEventWriter.flush();
            xmlEventWriter.close();

            // expected success
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I expected to see 3 tab in my output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><tag>
<formatter pattern="abc         xyz"></formatter>
</tag>
```

But I got

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><tag>
<formatter pattern="abc   xyz"></formatter>
</tag>
```

Comment: You are experiencing [Attribute-Value normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize): "*Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or checked for validity, the XML processor MUST normalize the attribute value...*". Inside the value of an XML attribute (such as your `pattern` attribute), whitespace characters (`#x20`, `#xD`, `#xA`, `#x9`) are normalized to `#x20`, which is what you are seeing. This is just how XML works. If you don't like this, try using an element instead of an attribute: `<formatter><pattern>abc   xyz</pattern></formatter>`

Comment: Thank you for the response. Does it apply to character reference as well ? If I pass &#009; as the attribute, for example, I got: 
    <formatter pattern="abc&#009;&#009;&#009;xyz"></formatter>  // 3 &#009; in input

It turns to 

    <formatter pattern="abc   xyz"></formatter>  // 3 tab in output

Comment: "*Does it apply to character reference as well ?*" - no. Read the link I provided earlier. Character references are handled as-is, only unencoded whitespace gets normalized. So yes, using `&#009;` (which can be simplified to `&#x9;` or just `&#9;`) will output a tab character.